# How can I pass the result of a local `curl` in the command line to a remote server in one line?

Tags: shell, curl, command-line

I'm looking to make something like the following work in a one-line shell.

```
curl -s icanhazip.com | ssh user@host 'php /path/to/script.php "[PASS_IP_HERE]"'
```

I need to pass my local IP to a remote server, preferably in one line.

Today I do it like this:

```
curl -s icanhazip.com // manually copy result
ssh user@host 'php /path/to/script.php "[PASTE_RESULT_HERE]"'
```

Assuming local IP is `1.2.3.4`, and remote IP is `5.6.7.8`, then the desired result is closer to:

```
> curl -s icanhazip.com
1.2.3.4
> ssh user@5.6.7.8 'php /path/to/script.php "1.2.3.4"'
//          How can I pass this dynamically? ---^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command substitution:

```
ssh -t user@host "php /path/to/script.php $(curl -s icanhazip.com)"
```

Comment: Wow. I figured command substitution would be run on the remote server in your example. So if my local IP was `1.2.3.4` and my remote IP was `5.6.7.8`, you're saying that the command substitution would pass `php /path/to/script.php "1.2.3.4"` to the remote server? Cool.

Comment: I didn't try command substitution because I expected it to pass the remote server's IP address instead of the local IP.  Resulting in `php /path/to/script.php "5.6.7.8"` (if `5.6.7.8` was the remote server's IP address).

Comment: I haven't tested it yet. What do you recommend?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I'm being clear. The whole goal is to pass the local IP (not localhost, but result of the local server's `curl -s icanhazip.com`) to the remote server. So if local IP is `1.2.3.4` (i.e. result of running `curl -s icanhazip.com` on local server), then my goal is to pass `1.2.3.4` to remote server like so: `php /path/to/script.php "1.2.3.4"`. There is no need in this case to pass remote IP to itself. Assuming local IP is `1.2.3.4` and remote server IP is `5.6.7.8`, how do you recommend passing `1.2.3.4` to remote server?

Comment: Desired result is closer to `ssh user@5.6.7.8 'php /path/to/script.php "1.2.3.4"'` but without having to paste `1.2.3.4` manually.

Comment: ok got it, I had it reversed. Try my updated command, it will pass local IP to php script.

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like:

```
curl -s icanhazip.com | xargs -I{} ssh user@host 'php /path/to/script.php {}'
```